# WCF HandleError System.InvalidOperationException A task may only be disposed if it is in a completion state

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, asynchronous, asynchttpclient

I am stuck on an issue that may be conceptual or something simple I am missing. I have a Desktop application that is making an async call to the server.

This involves multiple nested calls through several classes. I have kept it async the whole way down the call chain.

The main issue which I have been able to reproduce consistently is when I am passing an HTTP client to another service which makes an async Post.

The code snippets aren't %100 correct as is, just trying to show basic

```
 public async Task<bool> SomeTask(IEnumerable<Dto> dtoList)
    {

           var response = await _corepointService.PostCore(request, _idbContext);
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            {
                success = false;
            }
        }
        return success;
    }


 public Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostCore(Dto request, IDBContext 
                    dbContext, HttpClient _httpClient)
    {

        var dto = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            RequestUri = new Uri(request.Resource),
            Method = HttpMethod.Post,
            Content = new StringContent(request.Body, Encoding.UTF8,
                "application/json")
        };

        return _httpClient.SendAsync(dto);
    }
```

This is the other alternative I have tried, not passingin the HttpClient and creating a new one.

```
 public Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostCore(Dto request, IDBContext 
                    dbContext)
    {
        var _httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var dto = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            RequestUri = new Uri(request.Resource),
            Method = HttpMethod.Post,
            Content = new StringContent(request.Body, Encoding.UTF8,
                "application/json")
        };

        return _httpClient.SendAsync(dto);
    }
```

The error I am getting is

```
 WCF HandleError - System.InvalidOperationException: A task may only be disposed if it is in a completion state (RanToCompletion, Faulted or Canceled).
```

at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Dispose()
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.DisposeParametersCore(Boolean excludeInput)
     WCF HandleError - System.InvalidOperationException: A task may only be disposed if it is in a completion state (RanToCompletion, Faulted or Canceled).
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Dispose()
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.DisposeParametersCore(Boolean excludeInput)
     WCF HandleError - System.InvalidOperationException: A task may only be disposed if it is in a completion state (RanToCompletion, Faulted or Canceled).
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Dispose()
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.DisposeParametersCore(Boolean excludeInput)

I am consistenly getting this error when the Async Post is being made in the final service. I am just not sure if it is even related, or is some kind of race relation. Any help or links to async information is much appreciated. I have tried to find any related posts on SO and didn't find anything specifically regarding this.

Thanks!

Comment: did you mark your PostCore method with async in the actual code? are you awaiting the SendAsync call? `return await _httpClient.SendAsync(dto);` and `public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostCore(...`

Comment: @WhiteRuski I didn't mark the PostCore method async and await the SendAsync call. I thought by returning a Task with the HttpResponseMessage type that it would be sufficient. I can try this though! Thanks :)

Comment: added it as an answer with some formatting/etc to let other people find it easier :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a wrapper class in the Desktop client that was returning a task and expecting the method it was awaiting to be synchronous.

It was unrelated to the HttpPost or any of the async code in the server itself.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure the following:

`async` in `PostCore` method definition

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostCore(Dto request,
    IDBContext dbContext, HttpClient _httpClient){}
```

and 'await' the SendAsync call

```
return await _httpClient.SendAsync(dto);
```

Hope this helps!